# Writing to 4/4 midi grid with triplets for drums

Tags: notation, rhythm, drums, midi, setup

I'm trying to write the following to a MIDI grid and unsure exactly how it should be written. Any help would be great.

[image]

This is how i have the grid so far. 1/32 Quantize

T = Tom (Aka LT)

K = Kick (Aka BD)

```
1&2&3&4&
--------
T-T-T-T-
--------
K---K-K-
```

The above just doesn't seem to sound right. I believe the __3 __ indicating its a triplet is throwing me off.

Comment: What software or sequencer are you using?  That would help give you some advice as to what you are using and perhaps get a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, the 2nd "T" should not come at the second beat, but slightly earlier. You cannot fit a triplet into an exactly quantized 1/32 measure, since every triplet note needs to take up 10.66667/32nd of the measure, so all you can do is calculate the duration and try to approximate that, which at 120 BPM means it's 60/(120/4)/3=0.66666667 seconds per triplet note. But in this case the first triplet note is split in half, i.e. these are the durations:

```
T        T        T        T
K                 K        K
0.3333 | 0.3333 | 0.6667 | 0.6667
```